# How to do the The Thane of Voldrune quest

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Has anyone done the The Thane of Voldrune quest in Grizzly Hills? How do you get the dragon under control? Do you have to use the flame-imbued Talismans?

Answer (score 4):

If you are new to World of Warcraft, [WoWhead](http://wowhead.com) is a great resource for all things WoW.

For this specific [quest](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=12259/the-thane-of-voldrune), you can kill the thane without having to use the dragon. The dragon can be controlled  by using the talismans.